# Coordinator layout, Collapsing toolbar not collapsing

Tags: android, android-layout

The toolbar does not collapse on scrolling.
I even used a Nested scroll view. Though it collapses when i dont use
**app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"** . But then the content in **LinearLayout** is not visible.
here is my code

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="aman.com.quickcars.activities.CarInfoActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="this is a text view" />



        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</FrameLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header_car_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/place_holder"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/image_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_car_info);

    toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.image_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    collapsingToolbarLayout= (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(retrievedList.get(pos).getName());
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must remove the `FrameLayout` and keep `NestedScrollView` as a direct child of `CoordinatorLayout`